# Let $A = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x \ge 1, 0 < y < \frac{1}{x^2} \}$. Show that $A$ is measurable and that $m(A) < \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $A = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x \ge 1, 0 < y < \frac{1}{x^2} \}$. Show that $A$ is measurable and that $m(A) < \infty$.

It's not easy to verify the measurability of $A$ with Carathéodory's criterion so I assume we need to show it otherwise. We have that $$A=\{(x,y) \mid x \ge 1, y\in \Bbb R \} \cap \{(x,y) \mid x \in \Bbb R, 0<y<\frac{1}{x^2} \} = ((1, \infty) \times \Bbb R) \cap (\Bbb R \times (0, \frac{1}{x^2})).$$ Since each $((1, \infty) \times \Bbb R)$ and $(\Bbb R \times (0, \frac{1}{x^2}))$ are Borel sets they're measurable and since the intersection of measurable sets is measurable the set $A$ is measurable.

However I don't know how can I show that the measure is finite? What can I do here?

Comment: $A$ is the intersection of of a closed set and the preimage of an open set under a measurable funciton: $\phi(x,y)=\tfrac{1}{x^2}-y$, for $x\neq0$.

Comment: You sure about this set? Seems to me like the measure of $A$ is in fact $+\infty$.

Comment: Double checked. This was the problem statement. Indeed it would seem that $m(A) = + \infty$...

Answer (score 1):

Define $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid x>0\mbox{ and }0<y<\frac{1}{x^{2}}\}$.
Observe that
\begin{eqnarray*}
A & = & \bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,\infty)}\{(x,y)\mid x>0\mbox{ and }0<y<r<\frac{1}{x^{2}}\}\\
 & = & \bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,\infty)}\{(x,y)\mid x>0\mbox{ and }0<y<r\}\cap\{(x,y)\mid x>0\mbox{ and }r<\frac{1}{x^{2}}\}\\
 & = & \bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,\infty)}\{(x,y)\mid x>0\mbox{ and }0<y<r\}\cap\{(x,y)\mid x>0\mbox{ and }x<\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\}\\
 & = & \bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,\infty)}(0,\infty)\times(0,r)\cap(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}})\times\mathbb{R}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, it is clear that $A$ is a Borel set.

Comment: If you interpret that if $x=0$, then $\frac{1}{x^{2}}=+\infty$,
then (your $A$) is (my $A$) union $\{0\}\times(0,\infty)$, which
is also measurable.

Answer (score 0):

For the part of the problem that is finding the measure, you think of this  region as below the graph $y=1/x^2$ from $[0,\infty)$, but including the nonnegative $y$-axis and excluding the positive $x$-axis. Which as mentioned in the comments gives an infinite area, say as an indefinite integral.

You probably want to let your professor know about what seems to be an error.

I imagine they want to use $x\geq1$. In that case, checking that the measure is finite depends on how much background you are allowed to use. If you can just find the Riemann integral, then do that. If not, cover with infinitely many rectangles and then combine countable additivity with a convergent infinite series.

Comment: I have edited the question. They did want to use $x \ge 1$.